# MS Excel 2013: introduce sentence by some schrout

Tags: excel

Is there any possibility to do some kind of dictionary, so that I could write just "1" and excel will replace it with a sentence like "bla bla bla", "2" with "some other sentence"?

Comment: I'm not interested about drop-down-list

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-AutoCorrect-options-for-capitalization-spelling-and-symbols-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Would autocorrect not do this as you are typing and not after Edit mode is engaged? This would introduce i would imagine lots of issues if you are typing numbers into your same sheet. Also autocorrect is an Application level setting and wouldn't be limited to your specific workbook. You could add to your worksheet change event to check if the Target value is "1" or "2" and replace those values with your bla bla. This does required VBA which you haven't stated is an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dome something similar once using VLOOKUP, not sure if it fits your particular need (it does not "replace" the value, it puts it in another cell).

Say you have 2 sheets. The first one is named dictionary :

```
A   B    
1   bla bla bla
2   some other sentence
```

In another sheet, in cell B1, put : =VLOOKUP(A1,DICTIONARY!A:B,2)

Write 1 in your A1 cell and B1 should show  : "blablabla"

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1:**

You can use Excel AutoCorrect.
[image]

**Alternative 2:**
You can use Find & Replace functionality of Excel (and other Office software).

[support.office.com: Find or replace text and numbers on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-3a2c910f-01b9-4263-8db2-333dead6ae33)

Be sure to use some unique string in original text. Otherwise it could replace parts of text you dont want to replace.
Maybe something like :"repl1" or "x1x" or "dummyText1"